# Distribution Function Of a Random Variable X - Question

Tags: probability, random-variables

This is a homework question pretty much but I do not understand how to approach it.

The distribution function of the random variable X is given:

F(X) =

0, x < 0

x/2, 0 <= x < 1

2/3, 1 <= x < 2

11/12, 2 <= x <3

1, 3 <= x

I'm supposed to plot this distribution function. is this similar to those types of graphs where there are dots representing whether a point is open or closed with a line connecting the two? Sorry about the poor articulation, it's been a while since I've graphed anything.

The next thing I'm supposed to do is find P(X > 1/2), followed by P(2 < X <= 4) and P(X = 1). Having one of these answered - or a hint or link thrown my way, something I can learn, preferably - would be nice.

Comment: If you find $F(\frac12)$, that will tell you $P(X \le \frac12)$ and so you can deduce  $P(X \gt \frac12)$.  Similarly with $F(2)$ and $F(4)$.  For the final part, look at $F(1)$ and  the limit of $F(1-\delta)$.

Comment: Would F(1/2) fall under x/2? How would I proceed from there? Am I meant to plug it into that part of F(X), as in F(1/2) = (1/2) / 2 = 1/4?

Comment: As you say, $F(\frac12)=\frac14$.  So $P(X \le \frac12)=\frac14$.  Can you then say what $P(X \gt \frac12)$ is?

Comment: Would it be some value > 1/4? I'd say 1/4 exactly but the greater than operator isn't greater than/equal to.

Comment: If you know the probability of being less than or equal to a particular value, how do you find the probability of being greater than that value?

Comment: 1 - P(1/2) = 3/4? Am I interpreting this correctly? If there's no equal to middle ground, then the probability is going to be 1 - less than for greater than, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, or rather $P(X \gt \frac12)= 1-F(\frac12) = \frac34$  and now you have answered the first part of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can get the rest now. This was far simpler than I thought it'd be!

Comment: @SuperRhinocerus, what are you studying?