# Distribution Function - Finding $P(X < 3)$ for a given function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

this is the same as this:

[Distribution Function Of a Random Variable X - Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244543/distribution-function-of-a-random-variable-x-question)

but that question isnt as clear as I was hoping it was

The distribution function of the random variable X is given:

$$F(X) =
\begin{cases}0, &x < 0\\
x/2, &0 \le x < 1\\
2/3, &1 \le x < 2\\
11/12, &2 \le x <3\\
1, &3 \le x\end{cases}$$

I can find $P(x > 1/2)$ but I don't know how to find $P(2 < X \le 4)$ or $P(x < 3)$.

For $P(X = 1)$, I thought it was $1 - P(1) = 1 - \frac{2}{3}$ but Im not sure...

can I get an explanation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of a cumulative distribution function, you have:

$P(X \leq a) = F(a)$

$P(X=a) = F(a) - F(a^-)$

$P(a < X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$

$P(X < a) = F(a^-)$

Where $F(a^-) = \lim_{x\to a^-} F(x)$.

Comment: may i ask what the '-' superscripts on 'a' means?

Comment: Limit from the left -- see any introductory calculus book for more details.